# Parse JSON string using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm looking for some regex help on the following:

```
{ Start: '2019-10-21T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-21T15:30:00Z' }
```

I need to be able to just pull the start value from what is above. Ex: 2019-10-21T15:00:00Z

My regex is terrible and I don't even really have any semi-functional code to share.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a JSON parser, not regex.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what tool you are using. Regex works slightly differently in Python, Perl, JavaScript, grep, etc.

For Perl, you need: `Start: .\K[0-9TZ:-]+`

To test this on the command-line:

```
echo "{ Start: '2019-10-21T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-21T15:30:00Z' }" |grep -Po 'Start: .\K[0-9TZ:-]+'
```

Comment: It would be better to use a JSON parser here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I don't think we have enough information to make that determination. As part of a larger or import project - yes, I agree. As a one-off or proof-of-concept, a JSON parser may be overkill. Also, it was pointed out elsewhere that this is not proper JSON.

Comment: Fair enough +1, I commented before that information was known.  In any case, many JSON parsers can tolerate non ideal JSON to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things

this is not valid JSON.

```
{ Start: '2019-10-21T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-21T15:30:00Z' }
```

This is valid JSON.

```
'{ "Start": "2019-10-21T15:00:00Z", "End": "2019-10-21T15:30:00Z" }'
```

You can parse this using `JSON.parse()`, which will parse your string into a javascript object.

```
var jsonString = '{ "Start": "2019-10-21T15:00:00Z", "End": "2019-10-21T15:30:00Z" }';

var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(parsedJson.Start);
console.log(parsedJson.End);
```

Comment: thanks Malcor, I agree what i provided is not valid, but that is what is being returned when i console.log it. So somehow i need to be able to parse what is being passed. 

{ Start: '2019-10-22T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-22T15:30:00Z' }

Comment: If that's the output of `console.log` then it's already parsed. That's a typical javascript object. You should be able to access the Start and End properties.